# How can I replace `<?php echo ...; ?>` expression with `<?= ?> `?

Tags: php, arrays

From php 5.4, `<?= ...?>` can be used for replacement of `<?php echo ...;?>`.

So I would like to replace all of them in .php files in my project. How can I replace them?

Or can't it be possibly convert automatically?

I have found the script that replaces `array()` with `[]` ([thomasbachem/php-short-array-syntax-converter](https://github.com/thomasbachem/php-short-array-syntax-converter)). Do anyone know something like this?

(This may be present anywhere, but it is hard for google to search by queries with many symbols...)

Comment: You need change in `php.ini`.  _short_open_tag Default Value: On_

Comment: @FrayneKonok I'm assuming the OP is using PHP 5.4+. If that's the case `<?=` is always available regardless of the value in php.ini.

Comment: Look for `short_open_tag=Off` Turn it `On` if not.

Comment: Is there a particular reason *why* you want to replace these?

Comment: Thank you for comments. I'll turn `short_open_tag` on before replacing `<?php echo ...;?>`s.

Comment: @Mike Just for a change. The code with `<?= ?>` looks like modern php code. It is not much of a reason.

Comment: @ikuwow According to the changelog [here](http://php.net/manual/en/language.basic-syntax.phptags.php) short tags have *always* been available in PHP, so it's not exactly "modern".

Comment: There is http://fossil.include-once.org/phptags/ to automate rewriting to short echo tags.

Comment: Asking how to search and replace text is not on-topic for SO. Look at the manual for your text processing program. If you're looking for a script to do this for you, that's also off topic.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have short_open_tags enabled in php.ini, you will be able to use `<?= ...?>` instead of default open tags.

As for as converting all the program statements from

```
<?php
echo $var;
?>
```

to

```
<?=$var ?>
```

would have to be done manually. I do not know of any convertor script that automates it, although I found some scripts on github that does the reverse(converting short tags to long ones).

Comment: the question is for PHP 5.4. The ability to use `<?= ... ?>` [is always on](http://php.net/manual/en/language.basic-syntax.phptags.php)

Comment: Thank you for anwering my question. I understand it seems to be difficult to automate converting `<?php echo ` to `<?=`...

Answer (score 0):

In PHP 5.4.0, The tag `<?=..` is always available regardless of the `short_open_tag` ini setting. [Source](http://php.net/manual/en/language.basic-syntax.phptags.php)

**php.ini**

```
; This directive determines whether or not PHP will recognize code between
; <? and ?> tags as PHP source which should be processed as such. It's been
; recommended for several years that you not use the short tag "short cut" and
; instead to use the full <?php and ?> tag combination. With the wide spread use
; of XML and use of these tags by other languages, the server can become easily
; confused and end up parsing the wrong code in the wrong context. But because
; this short cut has been a feature for such a long time, it's currently still
; supported for backwards compatibility, but we recommend you don't use them.
; Default Value: On
; Development Value: Off
; Production Value: Off
; http://php.net/short-open-tag
short_open_tag=Off
```

> After that you can change your `<?php echo ?>` to `<?= ?>`

Comment: *after that you can change your <?php echo ?> to <?= ?>* - That's the whole point of this question. The OP is asking how to automate this. The rest of your answer doesn't actually answer the question.

Comment: the question is for PHP 5.4. The ability to use `<?= ... ?>` [is always on](http://php.net/manual/en/language.basic-syntax.phptags.php)

Comment: If someone Manually Off it then what, I just suggest the OP to check and use.

Comment: @FrayneKonok `5.4.0 The tag <?= is always available regardless of the short_open_tag ini setting.` ([Source](http://php.net/manual/en/language.basic-syntax.phptags.php)) - That should answer your question.

Answer (score -1):

in your php.ini change the tag: 
short_open_tag=Off to:
 **short_open_tag=On**. that would solve your problem